# Encoding a long to a VLQ byte array and writing it to System.IO.BinaryWriter

Tags: c#, binary, bit-manipulation, .net-4.7.1

This question is a follow up to to my last one here:
[Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51325504/need-help-writing-a-binary-reader-extension-method-for-a-specific-value-format/51344394#51344394)

In that question I asked how I could read a specific VLQ format, which I won't describe again but you can read it from my previous question.

Basically the result from harold was this:

```
static int ReadVLQInt64(this BinaryReader r)
{
    sbyte b0 = r.ReadSByte();
    // the first byte has 6 bits of the raw value
    int shift = 6;
    long raw = b0 & 0x3FL;
    // first continue flag is the second bit from the top, shift it into the sign
    sbyte cont = (sbyte)(b0 << 1);
    while (cont < 0)
    {
        sbyte b = r.ReadSByte();
        // these bytes have 7 bits of the raw value
        raw |= (b & 0x7F) << shift;
        shift += 7;
        // continue flag is already in the sign
        cont = b;
    }
    return b0 < 0 ? -raw : raw;
}
```

(This is just the int64 version of it)

This works beautifully to read such a value but now I need to be able to write such a value.
In short I need the reverse of that function. To take an int64 value and break it down into a byte array of variable length in the format described in the previous question.

Any help will be really appreciated.

Thanks for reading.

Edit: At a request from the comments i needed to provide some of my own code to build on.

```
public static void WriteVLQInt64(this BinaryWriter bw, long value)
{
    var bytes = new List<byte>();
    var i = 6;
    var j = 0;
    var shift = 0;

    while (true)
    {
        var andvalue = Convert.ToInt64(Math.Pow(2, i) - Math.Pow(2, j));
        j = i;

        var b = Convert.ToByte((value & andvalue) >> shift);

        if (b <= 0) break;

        bytes.Add(b);

        shift = i;
        i += 7;
    }

    for (int k = 0; k < bytes.Count; k++)
    {
        if (bytes[k] == bytes.First())
        {
            if (value < 0)
            {
                bytes[k] |= 128;
            }
            if (bytes[k] != bytes.Last())
            {
                bytes[k] |= 64;
            }
            continue;
        }

        if (bytes[k] != bytes.Last())
        {
            bytes[k] |= 128;
        }
    }

    bw.Write(bytes.ToArray());

    /* - Just for debug
    foreach (var item in bytes)
    {
        Console.Write(Convert.ToString(item, 2).PadLeft(8, '0'));
    }
    Console.WriteLine();
    */
}
```

I didn't post this before simply because it is a awful mess of a solution, and has way too much going on.
So i'll just rephrase my question... Is is possible somebody could help me compact that function down and remove a lot of the unnecessary stuff from it? such as the Math.Pow bit the numerous if statements and the numerous use of Convert.To...

Thanks again for reading.

Comment: As always, SO isn't "write for me the code"... You write some code, we help you. You write 0 code, we don't have to help you.

Comment: Ok, i updated the post with some of my own messy code.

Comment: Just to remind, that 64bit version needed `b & 0x7FL`, but not `b0 & 0x3FL` (for the first byte, the bits are never shifted out of range of an `int`, they're not even shifted).

Answer (score 0):

Added support for `long.MinValue` (it is a little more complex, because `abs(long.MinValue) > long.MaxValue`, so it needs special handling). Added separate support for `int`. Added checks for "illegal" values (otherwise you could build illegal sequences that would be too much big for an `int` or for a `long`).

```
public static long ReadVlqInt64(this BinaryReader r)
{
    byte b = r.ReadByte();

    // the first byte has 6 bits of the raw value
    ulong raw = (ulong)(b & 0x3F);

    bool negative = (b & 0x80) != 0;

    // first continue flag is the second bit from the top, shift it into the sign
    bool cont = (b & 0x40) != 0;

    if (cont)
    {
        int shift = 6;

        while (true)
        {
            b = r.ReadByte();
            cont = (b & 0x80) != 0;
            b &= 0x7F;

            if (shift == 62)
            {
                if (negative)
                {
                    // minumum value abs(long.MinValue)
                    if (b > 0x2 || (b == 0x2 && raw != 0))
                    {
                        throw new Exception();
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    // maximum value long.MaxValue
                    if (b > 0x1)
                    {
                        throw new Exception();
                    }
                }
            }

            // these bytes have 7 bits of the raw value
            raw |= ((ulong)b) << shift;

            if (!cont)
            {
                break;
            }

            if (shift == 62)
            {
                throw new Exception();
            }

            shift += 7;
        }
    }

    // We use unchecked here to handle long.MinValue
    return negative ? unchecked(-(long)raw) : (long)raw;
}

public static void WriteVlqInt64(this BinaryWriter r, long n)
{
    bool negative = n < 0;

    // We use unchecked here to handle long.MinValue
    ulong raw = negative ? unchecked((ulong)-n) : (ulong)n;

    byte b = (byte)(raw & 0x3F);

    if (negative)
    {
        b |= 0x80;
    }

    raw >>= 6;
    bool cont = raw != 0;

    if (cont)
    {
        b |= 0x40;
    }

    r.Write(b);

    while (cont)
    {
        b = (byte)(raw & 0x7F);

        raw >>= 7;
        cont = raw != 0;

        if (cont)
        {
            b |= 0x80;
        }

        r.Write(b);
    }
}

public static int ReadVlqInt32(this BinaryReader r)
{
    byte b = r.ReadByte();

    // the first byte has 6 bits of the raw value
    uint raw = (uint)(b & 0x3F);

    bool negative = (b & 0x80) != 0;

    // first continue flag is the second bit from the top, shift it into the sign
    bool cont = (b & 0x40) != 0;

    if (cont)
    {
        int shift = 6;

        while (true)
        {
            b = r.ReadByte();
            cont = (b & 0x80) != 0;
            b &= 0x7F;

            if (shift == 27)
            {
                if (negative)
                {
                    // minumum value abs(int.MinValue)
                    if (b > 0x10 || (b == 0x10 && raw != 0))
                    {
                        throw new Exception();
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    // maximum value int.MaxValue
                    if (b > 0xF)
                    {
                        throw new Exception();
                    }
                }
            }

            // these bytes have 7 bits of the raw value
            raw |= ((uint)b) << shift;

            if (!cont)
            {
                break;
            }

            if (shift == 27)
            {
                throw new Exception();
            }

            shift += 7;
        }
    }

    // We use unchecked here to handle int.MinValue
    return negative ? unchecked(-(int)raw) : (int)raw;
}

public static void WriteVlqInt32(this BinaryWriter r, int n)
{
    bool negative = n < 0;

    // We use unchecked here to handle int.MinValue
    uint raw = negative ? unchecked((uint)-n) : (uint)n;

    byte b = (byte)(raw & 0x3F);

    if (negative)
    {
        b |= 0x80;
    }

    raw >>= 6;
    bool cont = raw != 0;

    if (cont)
    {
        b |= 0x40;
    }

    r.Write(b);

    while (cont)
    {
        b = (byte)(raw & 0x7F);

        raw >>= 7;
        cont = raw != 0;

        if (cont)
        {
            b |= 0x80;
        }

        r.Write(b);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much! works very nicely. Apologies for the lack of code before, but now i understand that i need to show some work on the question beforehand, even if i feel it's terrible.

Comment: @plmjk Added the support for `long.MinValue` plus checks for illegal values plus a `int` variant.